# How to optimize the build time of a c++ project inside a container

Tags: c++, docker, cmake, makefile, dockerfile

I have a following Docker file with c++ project that installs dependencies, copy cpp-project and builds it.

```
FROM amd64/debian:bullseye-slim as builder
LABEL description="Build container"

# Update and install build dependencies
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get -y install \
    build-essential \
    cmake \
    libxmlrpc-c++8-dev \
    libxmlrpc-c++8v5 \
    libxmlrpc-core-c3-dev \
    libxmlrpc-core-c3 \
    xmlrpc-api-utils \
    curl \
    libcurl4-openssl-dev \
    libsqlite3-dev \
    sqlite3 \
    libxml2-dev &&  \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Copy source files
COPY cpp-project/ /usr/local/src/cpp-project/

# Specify the working directory
WORKDIR /usr/local/src/cpp-project/build

# Compile daemon
RUN cmake .. && make

FROM amd64/debian:bullseye-slim as runtime
LABEL description="Run container"

# Update apps on the base image
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get -y install \
    tini \
    libxmlrpc-c++8v5 \
    sqlite3 \
    libxml2 && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
    
RUN mkdir /usr/local/daemon
# Daemon bin
COPY --from=builder /usr/local/src/cpp-project/build/my-daemon /usr/local/daemon/my-daemon

WORKDIR /usr/local/daemon

#ENTRYPOINT ["/sbin/tini", "-v", "--"]
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/tini", "-v", "--"]
CMD ["./my-daemon"]

EXPOSE 40302
```

This way of building the images takes time, because every time code changes it copies source file and run cmake and make. All the previous built libraries is gone in the next build and cmake/make will not take advantage of the previous build as it is a fresh docker and previous build directory is not present.

Is it possible to modify or some kind of volume mount so that the build directory is persisted and next cmake/build take advantage of previous build libraries? Just wanted to speed up my development process on my local machine.

Comment: There is mount option in `docker run`. Like `-v host_path:container_path`

Comment: @kiner_shah. You do not run it. you do docker build ...

Comment: you can do this as a multi-step process, you have a build image which just has the development dependencies in, then you run the build image with mounted volumes, then you copy the built files into a runtime image. This also avoids having all your dev files in your runtime image, making it much smaller

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modern Dockerfiles allow you to specify that a persistent volume should be used for caching purposes. Replace your `RUN cmake .. && make` with:

```
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/usr/local/src/cpp-project/build,sharing=locked \
  cmake .. && cmake --build . && cp my-daemon /
```

and in your second stage grab `my-daemon` from `/my-daemon` instead.

The `sharing=locked` argument prevents multiple concurrent builds from interfering.

Comment: I am kind of reading the official documentation and cloud not manage to wrap my head around yet. Why is copy needed (`cp my-daemon /)` ? where are we copy the my-daemon to ? 
Can not I just it in the next stage like 
`COPY --from=builder /usr/local/src/cpp-project/build/my-daemon /usr/local/daemon/my-daemon`. OR since it is cache folder it will get lot in the second stage build ?

Comment: The temporary volume only sticks around for the command you give it. So you need to copy `my-daemon` to a place where the second stage's `COPY` can pick it up.

Comment: How does this  "temporary volume " persists when i make changes to my source code and run `docker build `  for second and third time etc. 

Does docker engine take care of it ?

Comment: Yes. As documented, it persists between runs.

Comment: Thank you very much for clearing that up.